# Get-TfsItemHistory not working TFS 2010

Tags: powershell, tfs

The issue is that executing the below command returns nothing. I know there are items with a checkin date greater than 12/5/2010. If I change the -gt to -lt I get thousands of records as expected but the -gt does not work and I cannot figure out wth is going on.. All I want is a distinct list of individual files from the TFS that have been checked in with the status of Edit afteer 12/5/2010 but I can't even get the -gt to work. Thoughts?

Running this command on the client which is Windows 7 x64. I have the October TFS Powershell CmdLets installed. TFS 2010 is installed on a Windows 2008 server.

```
Get-TfsItemHistory $/MyPath -recurse -all | where {  $_.CheckinDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-17)}  | Select-TfsItem
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think CheckinDate is what you want to use here.  Get-TfsItemHistory returns a list of changesets.  CheckinDate is on the files.

Try CreationDate instead:

```
Get-TfsItemHistory $/MyPath -recurse -all | where {  $_.CreationDate -gt (Get-Date).AddDays(-17)}  | Select-TfsItem
```